# How can i integrate these two separate procedures into one procedure? Or is this not possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Trying to get both blocks of code to run with one job. How would I be able to get the procedure to compile and then run ? Probably a dumb question but I couldn't find a answer on google. My code is below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertXMLDataTransfer(
 vROW_ID in xml_hours_load_2.ROW_ID%TYPE,
 vUTC_Offset in xml_hours_load_2.UTC_OFFSET%TYPE,
 vPROCESSED in xml_hours_load_2.PROCESSED%TYPE,
 vDATA_DATE in xml_hours_load_2.Data_Date%TYPE,
 vHR_UTC in xml_hours_load_2.HR_UTC%TYPE,
 vVALUE_TX in xml_hours_load_2.VALUE_TX%TYPE,
 vHR in xml_hours_load_2.HR%TYPE,
 vHR_NUM in xml_hours_load_2.HR_NUM%TYPE,
 vDATA_CODE in xml_hours_load_2.DATA_CODE%TYPE,
 vDATA_TYPE in xml_hours_load_2.DATA_TYPE%TYPE
                                              )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2(ROW_ID, UTC_OFFSET, PROCESSED, DATA_DATE,     HR_UTC, VALUE_TX, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, DATA_TYPE)
      VALUES (vROW_ID, vUTC_Offset, vPROCESSED, vDATA_DATE, vHR_UTC, vVALUE_TX, vHR, vHR_NUM, vDATA_CODE, vDATA_TYPE);
  execute immediate ('truncate table xml_hours_load');
COMMIT;
END;
/
/
DECLARE 
 vROW_ID xml_hours_load_2.ROW_ID%TYPE;
 vUTC_Offset xml_hours_load_2.UTC_OFFSET%TYPE;
 vPROCESSED xml_hours_load_2.PROCESSED%TYPE;
 vDATA_DATE xml_hours_load_2.Data_Date%TYPE;
 vHR_UTC xml_hours_load_2.HR_UTC%TYPE;
 vVALUE_TX xml_hours_load_2.VALUE_TX%TYPE;
 vHR xml_hours_load_2.HR%TYPE;
 vHR_NUM xml_hours_load_2.HR_NUM%TYPE;
 vDATA_CODE xml_hours_load_2.DATA_CODE%TYPE;
 vDATA_TYPE xml_hours_load_2.DATA_TYPE%TYPE;
  CURSOR cXMLHoursCursor IS (SELECT ROW_ID, UTC_OFFSET, PROCESSED, DATA_DATE, HR_UTC, VALUE_TX, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, DATA_TYPE FROM xml_hours_load);
BEGIN
  For v in cXMLHoursCursor LOOP
  insertXMLDataTransfer(v.ROW_ID, v.UTC_OFFSET, v.PROCESSED, v.DATA_DATE, v.HR_UTC, v.VALUE_TX, v.HR, v.HR_NUM, v.DATA_CODE, v.DATA_TYPE);
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a procedure from a job?

Comment: As it stands every time you insert 1 row into the 'xml_hours_load_2' table you truncate the 'xml_hours_load' table (which effectively commits anyway so your COMMIT is redundant). It would make more sense to copy all the records in and then truncate at the end. Also a simple INSERT based  on a SELECT would likely be quicker rather than row by row.

Comment: Sorry, i've misunderstood, it's nothing to do with jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProc AS
    CURSOR cXMLHoursCursor IS
    (
        SELECT ROW_ID, UTC_OFFSET, PROCESSED, DATA_DATE, 
            HR_UTC, VALUE_TX, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, DATA_TYPE 
        FROM xml_hours_load
    );

BEGIN
    For v in cXMLHoursCursor LOOP
        insertXMLDataTransfer(v.ROW_ID, v.UTC_OFFSET, v.PROCESSED, v.DATA_DATE, 
            v.HR_UTC, v.VALUE_TX, v.HR, v.HR_NUM, v.DATA_CODE, v.DATA_TYPE);
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Should do it

Note that you're committing after each insert which is not ideal for performance reasons. You can either commit at the end of the procedure or, even better, leave transaction control to the caller.

Comment: for some reason, the data is not inserting.  Would it be feasible for me to compile the first block of code as a stored procedure, and to set up a job to run the code in the second block? Or do i need to combine them all into one stored procedure and/or package?

Comment: @icerabbit Did you execute MyProc?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a single insert statement; no need for a procedure to loop through a cursor just to insert each row!

E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2 (row_id,
                              utc_offset,
                              processed,
                              data_date,
                              hr_utc,
                              value_tx,
                              hr,
                              hr_num,
                              data_code,
                              data_type)
SELECT row_id,
       utc_offset,
       processed,
       data_date,
       hr_utc,
       value_tx,
       hr,
       hr_num,
       data_code,
       data_type
FROM   xml_hours_load;
```

Once you've run the insert, you could then do the commit and the truncate of the xml_hours_load table, like so:

```
create or replace procedure your_proc is
begin
  INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2 (row_id,
                                utc_offset,
                                processed,
                                data_date,
                                hr_utc,
                                value_tx,
                                hr,
                                hr_num,
                                data_code,
                                data_type)
  SELECT row_id,
         utc_offset,
         processed,
         data_date,
         hr_utc,
         value_tx,
         hr,
         hr_num,
         data_code,
         data_type
  FROM   xml_hours_load;

  commit;

  execute immediate 'truncate table xml_hours_load';

end your_proc;
/
```

That will be more performant than looping through the result set row-by-row only to insert each row.

Comment: is this something i can regularly schedule to run as well? What is the con of using the stored procedure that i ran?

Comment: The con of using your row-by-row approach is that you’re doing a lot of context switching between PL/SQL and SQL - ie. Get a row, fetch it into a record, now insert it into a table, get the next row, rinse and repeat. Similar to if I gave you a jug to empty a bath; it’s doable but you’ve got a lot of to-ing and fro-ing between the bath and the drain. It’s a lot easier and quicker to just pull the bathplug! You could encapsulate the insert-select, commit and truncate into a stored procedure and then schedule a job to call it via dbms_scheduler.